# List name and link directories

Tags: php, html

I have a question.

I want to create a menu in php to display name and link foreach directories from `/public_html/`.
I create code, display name, but when you get into that directory, web links it no longer occurs because there is no folder.

Example:

I have this folder: /photos/ in it i have `folder1`, `folder2`, `folder3`
In each folder I have photos, and i want to keep displaying name and links for  `folder1`, `folder2`, `folder3`.

```
function theme_generate_header_page($dirs){
global $pa_setup,$themes_dir,$pa_user,$pa_theme;
ob_start();
$dir = new DirectoryIterator('photos');
if(is_array($dirs)){
foreach($dirs as $dir){
$dir_link=$dir['link'];
$dir_name=$dir['name'];
include $themes_dir.$pa_setup["site_theme"]."/header.tpl.php";}}
$contents = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
return $contents;}
```

Code for display:

`<a class="menu_button_item" href="<?php  print $dir_link; ?>"><?php print $dir_name;?></a>`

Thanx!

Comment: Please post your function code inline in the question, a link to some external site is _not_ a replacement for that. This is clearly explained in the "how to ask" section here. Thanks.

Comment: A little confusing use of two variables - $dirs and $dir. Please check that.